# How to specify parent directory as submodule path

Tags: git, git-submodules

How (if possible) to have a submodule path as the parent directory such that a `git submodule update --init --recursive` will clone the submodule in the parent directory of the current repository?

I tried doing that by creating a submodule in a nested folder in a regular way, then manually modifying `.git/config` and `.gitmodules` to have `path = ../` and modifying `.git/modules/mymodule/config` to have `worktree = ../../../../` but no luck.

I essentially want to let `git submodule update --init --recrusive` clone a repository in the parent directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  Git won't let you create stuff outside the working tree, because doing so would be a security violation.  (Imagine for instance one that creates and fills in `../../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd`.)